# PHP POST array to table

Tags: php

I new to PHP. I'm trying to make an Incidence of Coincidence (IC) calculator from bits and pieces of code that i've patched together from other peoples work.  It's all working fine except for the part where it is posted to table.  I want it to stop making new cells after 50.
I've been looking at it for hours and have tried several other methods but i've confused myself.  Any help please?

Here's the code that's writes the table:

```
<?php
  if ( $showTable ) {
    // display tabulated values
    echo "<table class=\"trans\" width=\"1000\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\">"; 
    for ( $i = 1; $i < 50; $i++ ) {
         echo "<tr>"; 
         for ($c=0; $c <$cols; $c++) 
         {
         echo "<td>"; 
         echo($cells.': '.round($history[$i+$c], 3));
         $cells++;
         echo "</td>"; 
         }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
     $i += $c; 
  }
     echo "</table>";  
?>
```

Comment: what is the error? how you expected it and what you got? what were the differences?

Comment: It will fill up the page with table cells.  I to have 10 columns and 5 rows. $cols=10 ... I expect to have 50 cells,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly,

```
<?php
  if ( $showTable ) {
    // display tabulated values
    echo "<table class=\"trans\" width=\"1000\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\">"; 

    for ( $i = 1; $i < 50; $i++ ) { // 50 rows will be created
    echo "<tr>";      
         for ($c=0; $c <50; $c++) // each row will contain 50 <td>
         {
         echo "<td>"; 
         echo($cells.': '.round($history[$i+$c], 3));
         $cells++;
         echo "</td>";
         $i += $c;
         }
     echo "</tr>";    
    }


  }
     echo "</table>";  
?>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Thanks very much.   I can't see how i missed it.  That value should be much smaller.  I only want 10 rows.  I changed the value $i and it worked perfectly.